# ASP.NET getting viewstate in global.asax

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to get at the viewstate in the global.asax file?  I am having a problem with viewstate on some clients and I want to log what the viewstate is in the Application_Error event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewState is posted to the server in a hidden input form-field named "__VIEWSTATE". Therefore, you can probably access the serialized ViewState using this:

```
Request.Form["__VIEWSTATE"]
```

But if you look at the source code of one of your pages (in your browser), you can see that the ViewState is just a (long) encoded string:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"
  value="/2RkRMb2dvLnBuZ2Ag0PD..." />
```

I'm not sure if logging that string will help you find any errors.

Comment: The ViewState is obfuscated to avoid tampering with it, so it not really a solution to try and deserialize it.

Comment: Request.Form["__VIEWSTATE"] comes back as null.

Comment: @Mike: are you redirecting to an error page? In that case, the ViewState will no longer be available.

Comment: I'm talking about the Application_Error event in the global.asax file.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old topic, but the answer to this question is a definite yes.  Here is the easiest solution.  In your page you need to capture the decrypted / deserialized viewstate in a session variable whenever there is an error.  In your .aspx page, or in your base form if your pages all inherit from a common class add the following method:

```
public void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Session["ViewStateData"] = this.ViewState;
}
```

Then in your global.asax.cs class add this:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["ViewStateData] != null)
   {
      StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
      System.Web.UI.StateBag vs = (System.Web.UI.StateBag)HttpContext.Current.Session["ViewStateData"];
      sbText.Append("Viewstate Data:\r\n");
      foreach (string key in vs.Keys)
      {
         try
         {
            sbText.AppendFormat("{0}={1}\r\n", key, vs[key]);
         }
         catch (Exception)
         { }
      }

      HttpContext.Current.Session["ViewStateData"] = null;

   }
}
```

Note that vs[key] might be a complex object and thus you might need to add special handling for certain "key" values to write out it's properties, or add a custom ToString() override method to that object so that it writes out the information that you want to see.